# On what condition horizontalAccuracy is negative&zero and how to simulate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cllocationmanager

I use

```
[locations firstObject].horizontalAccuracy
```

In

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

And I know

A negative value indicates that the location’s latitude and longitude are invalid.(horizontalAccuracy)

**Question:**

1) On what condition `horizontalAccuracy` is negative?
And is it means that when `horizontalAccuracy` is zero ,the position message is very nice(no miss)?

2) How can I simulate 1)? I want to know when 1) happens ,what will longitude and latitude be.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`horizontalAccuracy` is `-1` while the sensors are warming up and we have no location fix yet. It will never be `0`; the best you will get is likely to be about `10`, if that.

You don't need to "simulate" anything. Run the code on your device and it will very likely be `-1` initially.